# Remove Html Tags from textarea

Tags: html, tags, textarea

Is there a way to remove or not allow to put Html tags in a textarea?

I have a form that send email with a textarea where user put comments.

But I got some spammers, putting html code in the textarea, which appear a form of html when the mail is send.

How can I convince that?

Comment: The form is a mailer form? So there's no problem if people put HTMLs in it? What do you mean by `which appear a form of html when the mail is send`? You sure it's HTML, not some email header injection attempt?

Comment: like I put a input field or another textarea in the textarea, I actually receive the email with a inputfield and a textarea.

Comment: Not sure why they do that, but in that case I'll go with strip_tags() if I really-really need to **not** see any HTML tags in the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)
2. Use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) (recommended)

Comment: why would you suggest 2 PHP specific set up when there is no PHP tag on the question?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are taking input that is supposed to be text, but are treating it as HTML (by injecting it, unchanged, in an HTML document).

Pass the data through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to create an HTML representation of the entered text (before adding it to the HTML document).